# How to sum slider value to another value?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a slider in my web page which start with 50 and i have to calculate it's price with other inputs
50 equals to 0€ when i increase the slider the value should be added to my total input like

```
(sliderValue - 50) * 0.35
```

When i increase there is no issue
But when i decrease the value is not removed...

How can i manage it? here is an example

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("sliderHDD");
var output = document.getElementById("risultato");

      var lastVal = 0
      slider.oninput = function() {
        var value = this.value
                var prezzo = (value - 50) * 0.35;
        var totale = document.getElementById("totale")
        output.innerHTML = value;

        if (lastVal < value) {
          // increase
          totale.value = parseInt(totale.value) + parseInt(prezzo)
        } else {
          // decrease
          totale.value = parseInt(totale.value) - parseInt(prezzo)
        }
        lastVal = value

        document.getElementById("tothdd").value = prezzo;

      }
```

```html
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 50%" step="10" type="range" min="50" max="500" value="50" class="slider" id="sliderHDD"></td>
          <td><span id="risultato" align="left"></span></td>
          <td></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="tothdd" disabled="disabled" value="0.00" style="width:60px"></td>
          <td>€</td>
        </tr>
        <br>
        Total
        <input type="text" id="totale" name="CostTotale" disabled="disabled" value="0" style="width:45px" class="text">
```

As you can see if i increase slider to X the value will be 42 and even in total will be 42, but then if i change it's value again the total will be not as it have to be

Comment: Have you tried it? The problem doesn't seem to be happening and is working perfect

Comment: I imagine this could be the result of a lot of cumulative rounding errors, you are repeatedly multiplying by 0.35 then parsing as an int. You are also running this on `oninput`, which runs repeatedly for the range, effectively adding/subtracting more or less based on the speed you move the slider...

Comment: @coder9927 check the total

Comment: I recommend set the value in the event, like `totale.value = (this.value - 50) * 0.35` because comments above are right.